# Limit dropdown string to just the first word in the string

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I have a dropdown element with values like these:

`<option value="Bulletins">Bulletins, bulletin_type, comments, engineering, keywords, language_type, model_name, offLine_type, option_code, product_code, product_type, security_group</option>`

`<option value="Communication">Communication, comments, communication_type, engineering, keywords, language_type, model_name, offLine_type, option_code, product_code, product_type, security_group</option>`

I can't change the format but I can add javascript to the page. I want to be able to just display the string up to the first comma but have the rest of the string available for other things I need to do.
Is this possible?
Scott

Comment: There is no way to do it with CSS so you will need to remove the text and set it as a data attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the text into a data attribute and set the text to the portion you want.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#sel option").forEach((opt) => {
   opt.dataset.orgText = opt.textContent;
   opt.textContent = opt.textContent.split(",")[0];
});

document.querySelector("#sel").addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  const selectedOption = evt.target.querySelector("option:checked");
  console.log({
    value: selectedOption.value,
    data: selectedOption.dataset.orgText,
    text: selectedOption.textContent,
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="sel">
<option></option>
<option value="Bulletins">Bulletins, bulletin_type, comments, engineering, keywords, language_type, model_name, offLine_type, option_code, product_code, product_type, security_group</option>
<option value="Communication">Communication, comments, communication_type, engineering, keywords, language_type, model_name, offLine_type, option_code, product_code, product_type, security_group</option>
</select>
```